# Curl -F equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, curl, http-post, multipartform-data, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to use HTTPClient object in C# to send a post request to an API.
This is the CURL command:

```
curl -X POST https://zzz.zzz.zzz/yyy -F Key=abcd -F media=@"audio.aac"
```

I wrote the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace Speech2Text
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        curl().Wait();
    }

    static async Task curl()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        //Create List of KeyValuePairs
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> bodyProperties = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

        bodyProperties.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key", "abcd"));
        bodyProperties.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("media", "@audio.aac"));

        var dataContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(bodyProperties.ToArray());

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://zzz.zzz.zzz/yyy", dataContent);

        HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
        }
    }
  }
}
```

But I keep getting this:

```
{"code":400,"message":"Please use [media] for the media file field name in your POST request."}
```

Is there any issue in the dataContect variable or it's something else?

Comment: @w0lf Thanks for your comment. I am using the same method in my code above but I think it doesn't capture the parameters that I'm passing to HTTP request. Because, while the `media` parameter is sent, it doesn't understand it.

Comment: The problem is server side, not client side. Your code is ok. You already get JSON response for that.

Comment: Try remove "@" from "@audio.aac"

Comment: @x... didn't work. It's the name of a file that I should pass. Shouldn't it be a file object or something like that instead of string?

Comment: Then, ask the server, what the server really wants...:=) Probably file means, you must convert it to base64 and put it in post parameter.

Comment: When using curl, `@` slurps the content of a file. You're going to have to open the file stream manually and pull it into a byte array, or something similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When sending a POST it is important that the Content-Type you send to server is indeed the one the server expects. You can easily verify what is send with the `-trace` option  from [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

```
curl -v --trace - -X POST http://localhost -F Key=abcd -F media=@"image.txt"
```

When you run this you'll find somewhere in first few lines this:

```
00b0: 63 6f 6e 74 69 6e 75 65 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e continue..Conten
00c0: 74 2d 54 79 70 65 3a 20 6d 75 6c 74 69 70 61 72 t-Type: multipar
00d0: 74 2f 66 6f 72 6d 2d 64 61 74 61 3b 20 62 6f 75 t/form-data; bou
00e0: 6e 64 61 72 79 3d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d ndary=----------
00f0: 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d ----------------
0100: 2d 2d 61 61 62 64 66 31 66 66 38 35 66 66 0d 0a --aabdf1ff85ff..
0110: 0d 0a                                           ..
```

So curl is sending an Content-Type of `multipart/form-data;`

In your code you use the class [`FormUrlEncodedContent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formurlencodedcontent(v=vs.110).aspx) which states in its description:

> A container for name/value tuples encoded using application/x-www-form-urlencoded MIME type.

So that is not the correct Conent-Type.

A better match is the [`MultipartFormDataContent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.multipartformdatacontent.aspx) because it states:

> Provides a container for content encoded using multipart/form-data MIME type.

With the correct classes found we only need to build up the container:

```
var dataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var keyValue = new ByteArrayContent( Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abcd") );
dataContent.Add(keyValue, "key");

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    // open your file
    using (var fs = File.OpenRead(@"c:\path\to\audio.acc"))
    {
        // create StreamContent from the file   
        var fileValue = new StreamContent(fs);
        // add the name and meta-data 
        dataContent.Add(fileValue, "media", "audio.acc");

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(
                  "http://yoursite.org", 
                  dataContent);

        HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
        }
    }
}
```

Running this code reveals in [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler):

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="f7335f00-bc16-4518-ae7a-149491403792"
Host: yoursite.org
Content-Length: 1014
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

--f7335f00-bc16-4518-ae7a-149491403792
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=key

abcd
--f7335f00-bc16-4518-ae7a-149491403792
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=media; filename=audio.acc; filename*=utf-8''audio.acc
```

which is more in line with the trace output from curl.