# Generation of POST HttpWebRequest using a string with the headers and the body in c#

Tags: c#, http, post, httpwebrequest

I have a string which contains this post request:

```
POST /url=ws.walla.co.il/form/?itemid=2773368 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 797
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: https://localhost
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarynWW393YLgBegLQYK
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: https://localhost/?url=news.walla.co.il/item/2773368
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: he-IL,he;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: aeuid=247897859747575876; aeses=1; aelast=1466862543110; aestate=ab; aeb=true; _cb_ls=1; _cb=BTpqzMbWn1VDmMlcY; _chartbeat2=.1466862544444.1466862544444.1; _dy_ses_load_seq=11113%3A1469789072660; _dy_c_exps=; _dycst=dk.w.c.ws.frv2.ah.; _dy_geo=IL.AS.IL_05.IL_05_Tel%20Aviv; _dy_df_geo=Israel..Tel%20Aviv; _dy_toffset=-1; _dy_soct=12898.15511.1469789072; _dyus_8765945=34%7C360%7C0%7C3%7C8%7C0.0.1466859495876.1469789073827.2929577.0%7C210%7C31%7C6%7C116%7C4%7C0%7C0%7C0%7C0%7C0%7C0%7C4%7C0%7C0%7C0%7C0%7C7%7C4%7C7%7C0%7C0%7C0%7C0; _ga=GA1.1.1267733164.1466862541

------WebKitFormBoundarynWW393YLgBegLQYK
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fname"

myName
------WebKitFormBoundarynWW393YLgBegLQYK
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="phone"

042895673
------WebKitFormBoundarynWW393YLgBegLQYK
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

tomi@gmail.com
------WebKitFormBoundarynWW393YLgBegLQYK
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="subject"

topic
------WebKitFormBoundarynWW393YLgBegLQYK
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content"

text
------WebKitFormBoundarynWW393YLgBegLQYK
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="multiplefile[]"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundarynWW393YLgBegLQYK
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="terms"

on
------WebKitFormBoundarynWW393YLgBegLQYK--
```

how can I generate a POST HttpWebRequest and send it to the url in the first line? Attention the the parameters in the body of the post request.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to use the HttpWebRequest? Can't you use the HttpClient? Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38628425/curl-f-equivalent-in-c-sharp/38775391#38775391)

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter which object to use, but how can I use the string above in HttpClient? I need to use something that works for each post request and not specificly for this one.

Comment: Everything you need is in my answer I linked you to. If you give it a try and then let us know in this question if something needs special handling. I'm sure isn't the only answer about HttpClient.