# Send binary data with HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, post, httpwebrequest

I want to send some binary data from my WinForms c# application.

The server expects the data will be sent using `POST` request. I need to send several files and parameters, something like this:

```
file1=<binary data>
file2=<binary data>
desc1=<string>
desc2=<string>
```

I've searched that in Internet and MSDN and the code bellow is the most popular:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com");
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
webRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
using (Stream postStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    postStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    postStream.Close();
}
```

But I don't understand how to use this code to send several parameters? How can I set name for each of them?

Using `GET` I whould do `&file=...&file2=...&desc1=...&desc2=...` but using `POST` I have no clue what to do.

Comment: Can you use the HttpClient? Because then you can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38628425/curl-f-equivalent-in-c-sharp/38775391#38775391).

Comment: @folibis Do you have the option to post a json payload, i.e. ContentType = "application/json"? This would let you post something like a Dictionary<string, byte[]>.

Comment: Thanks guys! HttpClient solution looks is what I need. I'm going to try it now. Unfortunately I cannot change server behavior.